# Placing multiple objects inside a list view

Tags: android, listview

We are developing an Android project. In that project we need to create a list view with multiple objects.

Inside each list view item we need to show Name, Mobile, Checkbox1 and Checkbox2

We tried with various options and we are clue less how to get this done.

Comment: here: http://code.google.com/p/ubirule/source/browse/ is an example project with one textview and one checkbox, you may easily create more components/fields editing xml's

Answer (score 0):

You can create an .xml file, which contains a Layout (LinearLayout, RelativeLayout etc) and inside that layout put some Views like TextViews for the Name and Mobile and 2 CheckBox items for your checkboxes. I recommend [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20170930232747/http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) tutorial for more on ListView issues.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your own row layout and also your own ListAdapter implementation. The adapter needs to override `getView` to return your custom row view. There's a good example [here](http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/02/22/android-layout-tricks-1/) that extends an ArrayAdapter. There's another example [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20201026071253/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/08/custom-view-in-your-listactivity-and.html) that extends a CursorAdapter. Search the web for *android custom listview row* to get lots of other examples.